# How do I temporarily pause an XNA game?

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0, timing, pausing

Collision with an enemy should pause the game for 1.5 seconds.

My failed attempt:

```
bool tPause;
float timer;

public ovveride Update(GameTime gameTime) {
    if(!tPause) {
        // ...
        if(enemy.rectangle.Intersects(player.rectangle)) {
            timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
            tPause = true;
            if(timer > 1500) {
                tPause=false;
                timer=0;
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

What am I missing? How can I do this?

Comment: This code snippet says that when it IS paused it can never NOT be paused.  Time to mess with some breakpoints and test maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once there is a collision, the *timer* variable will not get updated anymore, because the code segment of your if statement will not be executed.

Instead, you can use an *else* statement, where you exectue the code, to update your *timer* variable.

```
bool tPause;
float timer;

public ovveride Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if(!tPause)
    {
        if(enemy.rectangle.Intersects(player.rectangle))
        {
            tPause = true;
            timer = 0;
        }
    }
    else // if you are in the paused state
    {
        // update the timer variable and check, if 1.5 seconds passed
        timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        if (timer > 1500)
        {
            // set the paused state back to false
            tPause = false;
        }
    }
}
```